# jquery drop down .val .html

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate a drop down list

I have the following:

```
    $('#dd_deg ').append($('<option></option>').val('hello').html('va1'));
```

What is the purpose of .val and .html. I see that val1 is what shows in the drop down but what is the purpose of .val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, [.val(value)](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

> Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

And [.html(htmlString)](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

> Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

You typically use val to get/set the value of input elements, and html to get/set the inner html of any element.

Answer (score 1):

`val()` sets the `value` attribute of the element, as opposed to `html(val)` which sets the inner-HTML of the element and, frankly, should be replaced with `text()` since it's a purely textual change/setting.

Incidentally, this question could have been easily enough answered by a visit to the jQuery API site, to use (in most cases) simply use the following approach:

```
http://api.jquery.com/<name of method you want information about>/
```

So, in the above question, you'd use the URL:

```
http://api.jquery.com/val/
```

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).